# how to update scope variable of a controller from a outside JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am a newbie to angularJS. I have a clarification on how to update a scope variable from a outside JavaScript function. I couldn't find a way over anywhere kindly help me out below are my code snippet for reference

```
var devices = {};
mainApp.controller('deviceDataController', function($scope) {
    console.log(devices);
    $scope.deviceDetails = devices;
});

function deviceFunc (data,index){ //here the data and index values are obtain after doing a for each for an array and data is an object
    device['device'+index] = data;
}


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Now if I run the code at the console.log line i get "object { }" but inside this the value is there but when i breakdown the object to it's first property it's saying undefined eg. console.log(devices[device0].devicename) gives me undefined.

If there is anyway to do it kindly help me out.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should not do that, because that's not the angular way to manage data. Try to rearchitecture your code.

But you still can do that with many different ways.

**Example :** if you want to access to a scope from outside, try :

```
angular.element(someElement).scope();
```

Full doc : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Comment: Thanks for responding... But I couldn't find a better way of doing it. Can you suggest me if there anyway?

Comment: Yes for sure, but you don't show enough. Where do you call deviceFunc ? Why isn't it in the controller ? Do you share data between multiple controllers ? If yes use a service.

Comment: deviceFunc is been called inside a $.each loop for breaking an array to do an ajax call to get the data which is coming in object format.

Comment: Can you create a Plunker ( http://plnkr.co/ ) with your code, that would be easier.

Comment: sure .. here is the link http://plnkr.co/edit/Grkl8AuvBQ71yEzupQHN .. check script.js

Comment: Ok so you should create a service where you store data. So the controller can access them with dependency injection. I won't do it for you, i just started here : http://plnkr.co/edit/yQD3q62YiiMPobw7Fyyh Try to read angular tutorial. Good luck.